# How can I use the same error page for multiple error codes in Tomcat?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, tomcat

I'm trying to send plain text error messages from a tomcat servlet, so that the responses may be presented to the user by the application.

I have the following in my web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>409</error-code>
    <location>/string_error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

And string_error.jsp is the following:

```
${requestScope['javax.servlet.error.message']}
```

This successfully gives me plain-text error messages for a 409 response. However, I would like to use this same page for any error in the 400/500 range, without manually specifying a new `<error-page>` block for each one. I would have assumed that `<error-code>*</error-code>` would accomplish this, but it does not. Does Tomcat provide a mechanism to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using a Servlet 3.0 container, such as Tomcat 7.0, then you can just omit the `<error-code>` (or `<exception-type>`) element to make it a global default error page.

```xml
<error-page>
    <location>/string_error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Since Servlet 3.0 those elements are namely optional.

However, if you're not on Servlet 3.0 yet, then you'd have to configure it at the container level. In for example Tomcat 6.0 (which is a Servlet 2.5 container), you'd need to create a custom error report valve class. You can then specify it as `errorReportValveClass` attribute of the [`<Host>` element](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html) in `/conf/server.xml` file.

For other containers, consult their documentation.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I'm not able to use Tomcat 7 yet.

Comment: It seems that one can define (as above) a global default error page in *addition* to any specific error pages, so that any error which is not caught by the specific error page will be caught by the global error page,

Answer (score 1):

You can add `error-page` elements by either the `error-code` or the (java) `exception-type` in Tomcat.  I do not think it can be made general as you have suggested.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404error.html</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/someJavaException.html</location>
</error-page>
```