# Configuring single jsp error page with different messages for different http errors

Tags: jsp, servlets, web.xml, http-error

I am developing an web-application.

I am looking to configure error pages in web.xml.

I want to make a **single error page with different error messages for different http errors like 400,404,etc.**

For example : I want to use the same error page "error.jsp" for all http errors. 
assume **if error 400 arises**, jsp should display **"Bad request"** 
and **if error 404 occurs**,jsp should display messgae as **"page not found".**

please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This in fact is possible and is fairly simple. I will post 3 ways here.

1) The Servlets 3.0 way: Provided that you have upgraded to the latest Servlets 3.0, you could very easily do this by omitting the `<error-code>` or `exception-type` element of `<error-page>` and just provide the `<location>` and create a default error.jsp for your application. 
`

2) Explicitly type in all the 400s and 500s and map them to your error.jsp in your `web.xml`; This is in case you are using an older container and don't wish to upgrade. There are not many of [them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

3) There is a third way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6513444/608170) (@BalusC's answer, I admit I respect that guy for his knowledge and his reputation on SO)

To output error-code specific messages in your error.jsp use  `${requestScope['javax.servlet.error.status_code']}` either in a `switch-case` or an `if-else-if` construct.